# pandas read_csv memory consumption

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am reading huge Pandas (Version 18.1, on purpose) DataFrames stored in csv Format (~ summed up 30 GB). Working with read_csv however, memory consumption grows to the double of the initial csv. files --> 60 GB. I am aware of the `chunksize` parameter. This however was way slower and didn't really reduce memory usage. I tried it with an 4 GB DataFrame. Having read the DataFrame, the script still consumed ~7 GB RAM. Here's my code:

```
df = None

for chunk in pandas.read_csv(fn, chunksize=50000):
        if df is None:
                df = chunk
        else:
                df = pandas.concat([df, chunk])
```

This is only a short version. I am also aware, that specifying the dtype saves memory. So here's my question. What's the best way (performance, memory) to read huge pandas DataFrames?

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.concat((x for x in pd.read_csv(fn, chunksize=50000))`

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunatelly this doesn't change anything.

Comment: A year later and I am using version0.22. Seems it's still a problem unsolved...I got similar memory error when reading a ~7G csv file. It's strange that on my MacBook with 16G memory, it worked fine. But on my Ubuntu17 with 32G memory, it threw out 'memory error'. The final dataframe on my MacBook says it's ~11G, which make sense...Anyone can help me understand it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the types of operations you want to do on the dataframes, you might find [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html) useful. One of its key features is allowing operations on larger-than-memory dataframes. For example, to do a groupby on a larger-than-memory dataframe:

```
 import dask.dataframe as dd
 df = dd.read_csv(fn)
 df_means = df.groupby(key).mean().compute()
```

Note the addition of `compute()` at the end, as compared to a typical pandas `groupby` operation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `chunksize` incorrectly. It is not meant to be used for simply appending to the dataframe in chunks. You have to break up a dataset in pieces so that you can process a large dataset one piece at a time. This way, only the chunk that is being processed needs to stay in memory.

Using `dtypes` and `usecols` is the best way to reduce memory usage.

It is hard to say because you didn't provide any details about the dataset, such as row count, row size, column data types, number of columns, whether it is clean and structured data etc. If the data in your columns is not consistent, it can cause unexpected upcasting and a memory spike. So you may need to pre-process it before loading the dataframe.

- Consider using the `category` data type for any object/string
  columns with low cardinality and low selectivity.
- Use `dtypes` to lower the precision of your numeric columns.
- Use `chunksize` to process data in chunks, not just to append it. Or use dask.